# Are there macros which can be used to test Erlang version in driver C code?

Tags: erlang, erlang-driver

Erlang R15B added `ErlDrvSSizeT` typedef, and R16B added `erl_drv_output_term` function and deprecated the old equivalent. Is there a way to test for these differences with preprocessor macros in order to support older Erlang versions with the same code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ERL_DRV_EXTENDED_MAJOR_VERSION` and `ERL_DRV_EXTENDED_MINOR_VERSION` macro values, supplied in `erl_driver.h`, to make decisions about features. Whenever the driver API changes, these values are suitably incremented. These increments are always explained in the Erlang/OTP release notes.

For example, Erlang/OTP R15B changed some API function parameter types from `int` to a new type `ErlDrvSizeT` to better cope with 64-bit platforms. You can test for this and compensate for it for older pre-R15B versions using the code below:

```
#if ERL_DRV_EXTENDED_MAJOR_VERSION < 2
typedef int ErlDrvSizeT;
#endif
```

This typedef allows you to use the type `ErlDrvSizeT` even for older driver versions.

As of this writing, Erlang/OTP version 17.3 and version 6.2 of the Erlang runtime system (erts) are current. For erts 6.2, `ERL_DRV_EXTENDED_MAJOR_VERSION` and `ERL_DRV_EXTENDED_MINOR_VERSION` have the values 3 and 1, respectively. The changes in [this Erlang/OTP commit](https://github.com/erlang/otp/commit/12d3d25535225934cb2190c82c1b5dae005f1cda) created these version values.